# What API to use if the output could be represented in XML or JSON

Tags: java, xml, json, gson

We have a requirement to fetch information from the following API http://www.viralheat.com/developer/sentiment_api#method1 which can throw the output in xml or json. What java api should I use, so that I can write a wrapper to parse this information which might be consumed by the UI in JSON format and by a standalone client in a XML format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org) as it is superior to other recommended alternatives when producing JSON, and for XML either:

- Use a JAXB implementation with JAXB annotations (Jackson can optionally support JAXB annotations as well, so very little overhead of 2 libs)
- Use [Jackson xml-databind](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-xml-databind) module to produce XML using Jackson itself (in format that is usually identical to JAXB produced)

I do NOT think that you absolute must use a single library or framework, and the result is often better if you just choose best choice for each separately. XStream, for example, is good for XML, but produces ugly JSON (and slowly at that).
Going from XML to JSON is error-prone due to format impedance and I have yet to see an XML-processing lib that produces JSON clean JSON efficiently (or even just clean or efficiently).

Answer (score 2):

I would use [Xstream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) which supports XML and JSon with mapping of data structures.

Answer (score 2):

**Note:**  I'm the **[EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php)** lead and a member of the JAXB 2 ([**JSR-222**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222)) expert group.

You can do this with MOXy, check out my blog post where one domain model with one set of metadata is used with both the JSON and XML formats of the [Google Maps Geocoding API V2](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/v2/):

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/binding-to-json-xml-geocode-example.html

**Address**

The following is a class from the example.  It leverages [MOXy's `@XmlPath` extension](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html), in addition to JAXB annotations:

```
package blog.geocode.json;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlPath;

@XmlType(propOrder={"country", "state", "city", "street", "postalCode"})
public class Address {

    @XmlPath("Placemark/ns:AddressDetails/ns:Country/ns:AdministrativeArea/ns:Locality/ns:Thoroughfare/ns:ThoroughfareName/text()")
    private String street;

    @XmlPath("Placemark/ns:AddressDetails/ns:Country/ns:AdministrativeArea/ns:Locality/ns:LocalityName/text()")
    private String city;

    @XmlPath("Placemark/ns:AddressDetails/ns:Country/ns:AdministrativeArea/ns:AdministrativeAreaName/text()")
    private String state;

    @XmlPath("Placemark/ns:AddressDetails/ns:Country/ns:CountryNameCode/text()")
    private String country;

    @XmlPath("Placemark/ns:AddressDetails/ns:Country/ns:AdministrativeArea/ns:Locality/ns:PostalCode/ns:PostalCodeNumber/text()")
    private String postalCode;

}
```

**Demo**

The standard JAXB APIs are used to do the conversions to/from JSON and XML:

```
package blog.geocode.json;

import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.stream.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Address.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

        // XML
        XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
        StreamSource xml = new StreamSource("http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&output=xml&sensor=false&key=YOUR_KEY_HERE");
        XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(xml);
        xsr.nextTag(); // Advance to kml tag
        xsr.nextTag(); // Advance to Response tag
        JAXBElement<Address> addressFromXML = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xsr, Address.class);
        marshaller.marshal(addressFromXML, System.out);

        // JSON
        unmarshaller.setProperty("eclipselink.media.type", "application/json");
        StreamSource json = new StreamSource("http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&output=json&sensor=false&key=YOUR_KEY_HERE");
        JAXBElement<Address> addressFromJSON = unmarshaller.unmarshal(json, Address.class);
        marshaller.setProperty("eclipselink.media.type", "application/json");
        marshaller.marshal(addressFromJSON, System.out);
    }

}
```